# efficient way to fill a series of zeros with values at specific positions

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I would like to find an efficient way to fill a series of zeros with values at specific positions, based on the index. Here is some exemplary code:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_0 = {x: 0 for x in range(1, 11)}
ser_0 = pd.Series(dict_0)

dict_vals={2:0.1, 5:0.9}
ser_vals=pd.Series(dict_vals) 

ser_composed = pd.concat([ser_0[~ser_0.index.isin(ser_vals.index)],
ser_vals[ser_vals.index.isin(ser_vals.index)]])
ser_composed.sort_index()
```

As I want to apply it to much data, I'd like to find a way to do it more efficiently.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) is exactly what you're looking for.

> **Note:** It always modifies the Series in place. If you don't want this, make a copy beforehand.

```py
ser_0_original = ser_0.copy()

ser_0.update(ser_vals)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you're creating a dataframe with zeros first to be filled afterwards, consider directly creating the series based on `dict_vals`, along the lines of

```py
pd.Series(dict_vals, index=range(1,11)).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use broadcasting

```
ser_0[dict_vals.keys()] = list(dict_vals.values())
```

This will modify `ser_0`, if you want to preserve it use a copy

```
ser_composed = ser_0.copy()
ser_composed[dict_vals.keys()] = list(dict_vals.values())
```

Output

```
1     0.0
2     0.1
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.9
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
```